# Probability of multiple wins in a series of evenly matched teams

Tags: probability

24 evenly matched players are divided into 6 teams. (Evenly matched by virtue of golf handicaps). Team assignment is random. One player frequently wins, irrespective of which team he is assigned.
I assume that in a fair game each player has a one in six chance of winning. In a series of 20 games what are the chances of one player being on the winning team 8 times? Similarly what are the chances of that same player being on the winning team 30 times in a 100 game series?  Is the game fair?

Comment: could you add some of your own thoughts? When does a team win?

Comment: What do you mean by "One player *frequently* wins" ? Then you say each *player* has a one in six chance of winning. Then you talk of a winning *team*. I can't understand the question. Is it exactly copied from a textbook or have you made it up ?

Comment: 24 players are divided into six four man teams. all players are evenly matched skill wise. Teams are newly selected for each game. The winning team has the lowest golf score. t

Comment: 24 players are divided into 6 four man teams. All are evenly matched. Lowest score of the team wins. One player is on the winning team repeatedly, sometimes three times in a row, other times 5 out of 10. What are the chances of the same person being on the winning team 8 out of 20? I would think winning three in a row is 1/6*1/6*1/6. HOw a bout 30 out of 100, or 8 out of 20 games